# Uploading Table in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: table, google-earth-engine

I am trying to upload a table (shape) in Google Earth Engine. I have never had problems when I tried to upload a table but this time I am having the next problem:

> Error: Encountered 1 bad features during table ingestion.

Does anyone know why is the problem?

I tried to simplify the shape (using less polygons) and does not give me the error but has been carrying the layer for 5 days.

Comment: Have you tested the feature geometry for validity? For example, 'ST_IsValid' in PostGIS,  'check validity' tool in QGIS, or similar in ArcGIS? That would be my first step.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] which leads into the [help] which says that there should be no chit chat like thanks and signatures in posts here.

Comment: If you are able to share the shape(file?) that you are trying to upload, others can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: How can I share the shapefile?